# SQL Comparing Data Keywords

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Good morning,

I have been searching all over google for an answer to this so was wondering if anyone could help me out? Basically I have a database table, which consolidates keywords for example: dog, cat, horse, mouse. This is displayed as a result. However I need to create some SQL to say if two of those keywords exists, e.g horse and cat, then display these results. This would then allow us to go down X route.

Another example or issue which is a work around is to have a list of keywords, and then store this as a value, this would mean if someone typed in: my dog is violently attacking neighbours cats, it would detect dog and cat and would bring the user to a specific outcome..

```
declare @teststring varchar(512) = '{KEYWORD}' 
select top 1 k.type 
from (values 

('pet', '1'), ('dog', '1'), ('cat', '1')

) k(word,type) where @teststring like '%' + k.word + '%' 
group by k.type 
HAVING COUNT(1) >=2
order by COUNT(1) desc
```

As you can see this is storing cat, dog and pet. This then means if someone types my pet is a dog then it would go down a conditional route. (We then store the answers people put into {Keyword1}

So my issue here is I am limited to characters I can use in my SQL field. So I have created two lists (one list above with pet cat and dog.). Another list I have has exactly the same but (rabbit, hamster and horse). This is stored in {Keyword2} I want to be able to write some SQL that says if any of the keywords in {Keyword1} and {Keyword2} have been entered to then go down a specific conditional route. so if someone types by rabbit has been attacked by my dog it would detect rabbit and dog and would make this conditional and go down there.

I hope this isn't too confusing? I have thought about nested sql and inner joins but I am not sure this will do what im asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where's your problem, you seem to have it already covered, unless, you're having trouble making actionable code?

Maybe do this first:

- Dispose of `order by COUNT(1) desc`,
- Change `>=2` to `>=1`,
- Add your other keywords after cat with a different number, for example `('cat', '1'), ('keys', '2'), ('shirt', '2')`,
- Replace `top 1 k.type` with any placebo, like `1` or `'A'`,

Then, add this afterwards:

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT >= 2
    /* Do some stuff, because both keywords were used */
```

The concept is, if you wanna conditionally run some code, you'll usually need `IF / ELSE`, perhaps sometimes you can instead use `TRY / CATCH` or loops.

The `@@ROWCOUNT` isn't the mainstream way of checking in an `IF`, but it makes do many times, and I wanted to intervene on your code the least amount possible, for now. I might be even not getting you right to begin with.

The changes on your original query were aimed to have it produce an amount of records corresponding to how many keyword groups were found. Later on, that would be contested against `@@ROWCOUNT` as you have probably seen.

Hope I helped. All of this can be better done for sure, maybe when we can confirm what you're looking for.

Comment: I think I may have explained it a little bit wrong.   Basically I am limited in the amount of SQL I can write per statement.   So, one of our colleagues writes a sentence, from this sentence we want to extract keywords. The problem is where I cannot store enough keywords in the SQL statement for it to extract from, so I make multiple statements. The problem is linking two statements together. For example, I am looking for 'Dog ate the food'.  In one statement, the keyword 'Dog' is there. In the other statement 'food' is there. So, my question is, is there a link statement 1/2

Comment: 2/2    which can take one keyword from the first statement, find it, and carry onto the next statement to find the second keyword - Link the two and give me an answer?   We currently have to do it this was as there is no access to writing to tables.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but I'm still lost, you said you can run 2000 characters of SQL, is that once or as many times as you want? If you created temp. table in first 2000, can you use it in the second 2000 or do you have to create it again? Colleague wrote "*dog ate the food*", you want an answer to be something like "*both dog and food found*", "*dog found*", "*food found*", or "*nothing found*"?

Answer (score 0):

If you can store you keywords as tables you can use intersect:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (KeyWord VARCHAR (100))
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (KeyWord VARCHAR (100))

    INSERT INTO @table1 
    VALUES 
    ('dog'),('rabbit'),('dragon'),('cat')

    INSERT INTO @table2
    VALUES 
    ('dog'),('rabbit'),('ogre'),('whale')

    SELECT KeyWord FROM @table1
    INTERSECT
    SELECT KeyWord FROM @table2
```

Comment: Thank you, we can store the results temporarily in what we call a databox, is their anyway we can use it in that way? 

Also we are limited on the characters in SQL e.g. we can only enter 2000 characters of SQL code. We have around 100 keywords in each list. Also we do not have any write, update permissions as we can only read SQL. However we can declare temporary tables.

Comment: Im not sure what a databox is pal. What i'm getting at is if you can store your input key words as a temp table, or table variable. You can compare to your table of existing key words easily using intersect. You may need to consider enforcing some casing and trims on the data.

Comment: Ah ok well a databox is a temporary table so to speak, it just stores the answer in say databox01 and we can then pull through what ever was inputted into that somewhere else. 

I see, how do I work around the character limit though? For example I can have 100 keywords, I can break this down into groups of 10 for example, but I will need to use multiple sql statements, do I have the select and intersect as a separate statement linking to these?

Comment: When I run your statement I get the following: Unable to process multiple rows returned

Comment: Ok, am I right in my understanding that you are using a homebrew or 3rd party application to interact with SQLServer? It seems like you are hitting the limitations of this application. Temp tables and (#tablename) and variable tables (@tablename) only persist for the current execution. You could look at using global temp tables (##tablename), however these have their own problems. This is a tricky one to help with, without really understanding the environment and limitations you are working with.